# How to build a proxy to monitor database

Tags: delphi, proxy, delphi-xe2, indy10

I have a network with a InterBase database. On this database server I want a Delphi program what monitors the connections/data to and from the database.

So when a client connects to the InterBase server the Delphi program will catch the connection (port 3050) and passes it through to the InterBase (port 3050). So the program will have to listen to the same port as the InterBase?

The main purpose is to detect network problems like CLOSE_WAIT and other loss of connection to the database. I want to know when this happens. Also I want to cache the data, so when a connection problem occurs  it can continue for some milliseconds. If connection is down for longer I want a signal to the clients, so they have to stop transmitting.

I am new to Delphi (and Indy). But I can’t find examples how to do this. All the search hits is how to make connections behind a proxy. But I have to make my own ‘proxy’.

I use Delphi XE2 – Indy 10.5.8.0

Comment: "Point in the right direction" is a little too vague for Stack Overflow. What specific part of the task are you having trouble with? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea at all (you'll have to completely parse the client-server protocol Interbase uses, so expect a pretty hefty program that will also have a serious impact on performance and scalability).  On top of that, you cannot have two programs listening on the same port on one computer.  There must be easier solutions to whatever your problem is.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Have you considered just using the free [Interbase Performance Monitor](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23629)? Seems to do all the things you said you wanted.

Comment: Since you haven't stated that this proxy should do anything other than make the connection, any transparent proxy will do, even my own yProxy (simply turn off the yEnc decode feature).

Comment: @fvu, there's already a [MySQL proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) (you can transform queries). It's not that big of an effort.

Comment: @MarcusAdams there's at least 1 for Interbase as well, but go back to the original question: to the best of my knowledge IB is written in C, meaning that OP will have to reimplement, in Delphi the whole protocol stack in Delphi if he wants to understand what goes over the wire.  I honestly think that kind of task is not within his reach at this time.